# Src attribute switch with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a simple switch of `<img src="...">` depending on the present `src` with JavaScript. So if the image `#plus_1` is clicked, the script should check if the string `'plus'` is in the src attribute, and if yes, the src attribute should change. 
Not sure what mistake I made, help would be very much appreciated!

JavaScript:

```
   function ek_ak(id) {
            var ement = document.getElementById(id);
            if (ement.img.src.includes("plus") == true) {
                ement.img.src == "minusred.png";}
        }
```

HTML

```
<img src="plusred.png" id="plus_1" onclick="ek_ak('plus_1')"/>
```

Comment: Hint : `=` vs `==`

Comment: `ement.img.src = "minusred.png"`

Comment: and `includes` function not supported by IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers:

- `ement` is already a DOM element: it has no `img` property but you can access `src` on it directly;
- Regular expressions can be used instead of `String#includes`;
- You should use `=` as the assignment operator, instead of `==` (loose comparison).

```js
function ek_ak (id) {
  var ement = document.getElementById(id);
  if (/plus/.test(ement.src)) {
    ement.src = "minusred.png"
    console.log(ement.src)
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="plusred.png" id="plus_1" onclick="ek_ak('plus_1')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can directly send the element to the function using `onclick="ek_ak(this)`. This will avoid the unnecessary call to retrieve the element.
- To get the `src` you can simply call `element.src`. The element is your `img`
- The call `.includes(..)` is returning a boolean value. You do not need to add `== true`.
- You were using `element.src == "minusred.png`. `==` is used to compare elements not to assign. You should use `=`

```js
function ek_ak(element) {
  console.log("Current src = " + element.src);
  if (element.src.includes("plus")) {
    element.src = "minusred.png";
    console.log("Next src = " + element.src);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="plusred.png" id="plus_1" onclick="ek_ak(this)" />
```